# Editing a HTML/CSS theme and can't seem to enable it to show SOLD OUT

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes, shopify

So I am editing a Shopify theme similar to this: https://fashe-theme.myshopify.com/collections/all

For this theme, it should disable the product and have a sold out overlay, disabling the user from entering the product page.

Here's the product.liquid:

```js
<!--  -->
      <div class="p-t-33 p-b-60">
        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_buy">
          <div class="form-group p-b-10"  {% if product.variants.size == 1 and product.variants.first.title contains 'Default' %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>
            <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="form-control">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
              {% if variant.available %}
              <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>
              {% else %}
              <option disbled="disabled">
                {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
              </option>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
            {% if product.available and product.variants.size > 1 %}
            
            {% for option in product.options %}
            {% include 'swatch' with option %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            {% if settings.product_quantity_enable %}
            <div class="flex-r-m flex-w p-t-12">
              <div class="w-size160 flex-m flex-w">
                <div class="flex-w bo5 of-hidden m-r-22 m-t-10 m-b-10">
                  <button class="btn-num-product-down color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                    <i class="fs-12 fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                  <input class="size8 m-text18 t-center num-product" type="number" id="Quantity" name="num-product" value="1">
                  <button class="btn-num-product-up color1 flex-c-m size7 bg8 eff2">
                    <i class="fs-12 fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-addcart-product-detail size9 trans-0-4 m-t-10 m-b-10">
                  <!-- Button -->
                  <button class="flex-c-m sizefull bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="{{ 'products.product.loading' | t }}">
                    {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if settings.product_quantity_message %}
            <span id="variantQuantity" class="variant-quantity"></span>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

Here's the product-grid-item.liquid code where it shows the thumbnail of the product:

```js
{% unless current_collection %}
{% assign current_collection = collection %}
{% endunless %}

{% assign on_sale = false %}
{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
{% assign on_sale = true %}
{% endif %}

{% assign sold_out = true %}
{% if product.available  %}
{% assign sold_out = false %}
{% endif %}
{% assign img_size = settings.img_size_grid %}
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="block2">
  {% assign product_created_at = product.created_at | date: '%s' %}
  {% assign time_ago = 'now' | date: '%s' | minus: product_created_at | divided_by: 86400 %}
  {% assign product_new_time = settings.product_new_time | times: 1 %}
  <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative {% if time_ago < product_new_time %}block2-labelnew{% endif %} {% if on_sale %} block2-labelsale{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
      <img class="" src="{{ product.featured_image.src | img_url: img_size }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}">
    </a>
    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4" onclick="location.href= '{{ product.url }}'" >
      <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="block2-btn-addwishlist hov-pointer trans-0-4">
        <!-- <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart_alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="icon-wishlist icon_heart dis-none" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
      </a>
      <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4" data-toggle="tooltip" data-loading-text="{{ 'products.product.loading' | t }}" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.variants.first.id }}', '{{ product.title }}');">
          {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
    <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5">
      {{ product.title }}
    </a>
    {% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}
    <span class="block2-oldprice m-text7 p-r-5">
      {{ product.compare_at_price_max | money }}
    </span>
    <span class="block2-newprice m-text8 p-r-5">
      {{ product.price | money }}
    </span>
    {% else %}
    <span class="block2-price m-text6 p-r-5">
      {{ product.price | money }}
    </span>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer this question without having a live demo of it where one could investigate the problem with debugging tools of a web browser.

I suggest you use the Firefox Debugging Tools to see how the DOM is built up on the rendered page and where the layer is located you would like to see. Maybe it is behind another layer. Or maybe it is no there. You have to do this by yourself, maybe with some tutorial on how to user the debugger: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yueecwKDZxQ

Otherwise you would have to share the rendered HTML and all CSS of the page.

In the first code fragment you only show a select option for disable. In the second code fragment you only define the variable `sold_out` but you don't use it. I think you should use it somewhere to render a sold-out layer...